How to deal with outliers in panel data?
When we have cross-sectional data, we can easily detect and remove outliers. But how should one approach outliers when we are dealing with panel data? Since we have $i$ entities and $t$ times periods, we probably cannot simply remove one observation and remain with an unbalanced panel, I guess. Is it then advisable to remove the full entity where there is an outlier in one of the variables and have a smaller dataset?

I don’t agree with your opening sentence. The vast discussion of outliers on CV alone shows that the question is complicated and contentious. In mainstream statistics a widespread view is that outliers should only be removed if they are utterly impossible values that can’t be corrected.

Hence I advise (1) study of the most popular threads on outliers (2) explaining why you think you need to remove outliers (3) explaining what analysis you want to do for which unbalanced panels would be unacceptable.
